# NullInjector error- No provider for [[Object object]->[object Object]]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

When a user selects a row within a item a object (contact) is passed to the openContactModal function:

*contacts.page.html*

```
<ion-item class="notification-item" lines="none" *ngFor="let contact of haematology">
        <ion-row class="notification-item-wrapper" (click)="openContactModal(contact)">
```

The Function is executed in *contacts.page.ts*

```
openContactModal(contact){
   //OPpen contact modal
   console.log("Open contact modal for contact: " + contact);
   this.modalCtrl.create({
     component: ContactmodalPage,
     componentProps: {contact : contact}
   })
    .then(modal=> {
      modal.present();
      return modal.onDidDismiss();//called when mdoal closed
    })
   
 }
```

This is the modal *contactmodal.page.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavParams} from '@ionic/angular';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
import {Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const {Browser} = Plugins;


interface Contact {
  //Create a data structure for the conatct passed fomr calling class
  position : '';
  name : '';
  phone : '';
  email : '';
  department : '';
}



@Component({
  selector: 'app-contactmodal',
  templateUrl: './contactmodal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contactmodal.page.scss'],
  //providers: [NavParams]
})


export class ContactmodalPage implements OnInit {

  /**
   * This modal is openend when user taps on a contact 
   * in the Tests list in Contacts.page.ts
   * NavaParmtere var takes data sent (a contact item ) form the calling class ModalControler.create methiod
   * Modal.onDimiss retuns data to calling class (Contact.page..ts) if needed
   * Tutorial https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-modal-popovers-pass-receive-data/
   * Alternatively- Input() will receive the data passed form teh calling class- Contact.page.ts  which passes a Test item
   */

   public imagePathway : string;

@Input() contact : Contact;

public data = {
  position : '',
  name : '',
  phone : '',
  email : '',
  department : ''
}

  constructor (private modalcontroller : ModalController,
    private navParams : NavParams,
    private callNumber : CallNumber){}


  ngOnInit() {
    //Assign the contact details 
    this.data = this.contact;
    console.log("contact-modal ngOnIt: got thise fomr contacts page : " + this.data);
    this.getImageName();
  }

  getImageName(){
    //Set image depending on deprtment

    switch (String(this.data.department)){
      case "Haematology": {
        this.imagePathway="../../../assets/tests/tests6.jpg";
        break;
      }
      case "Biochemistry": {
        this.imagePathway="../../../assets/tests/bio3.jpg";
        break;
      }
      case "Microbiology": {
        this.imagePathway = "../../../assets/tests/micro4.jpg";
        break;
      }
      case "Histology" : {
        this.imagePathway = "../../../assets/tests/histology2.jpg";
        break;
      }
      case "Transfusion" : {
        this.imagePathway = "../../../assets/tests/transfusionIcon.jpg";
        break;
      }
      case "Immunology": {
        this.imagePathway = "../../../assets/tests/transfusionIcon.jpg";
        break;
      }
      default: {
        this.imagePathway= "../../../assets/tests/tests6.jpg";
      }

    }
    console.log("test-mpdal.ts: IMage pathway set: " + this.imagePathway);
  }

  async closeModal(){
    //close this modal and pass any data back to contact [age calling class
  const onCloseData : String = "Contact Modal Closed";
  await this.modalcontroller.dismiss(onCloseData);

  }
```

This is the error thrown:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(ContactsPageModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object]
> -> [object Object] -> [object Object] -> [object Object]]: NullInject

Ive been searching around for sometime and feel I am getting nowhere.

Any input on what this error means and a possible solution much appreciated.

Update: As requested this is the contact.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ComponentsModule} from '../components/components.module';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ContactsPage } from './contacts.page';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Contact } from '../modals/contactmodal/contactmodal.page';
import { ContactmodalPageModule} from '../modals/contactmodal/contactmodal.module';


//import { ContactmodalPageModule} from '../modals/contactmodal/contactmodal.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ContactmodalPageModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: ContactsPage}])
  
  ],
  declarations: [ContactsPage]
})
export class ContactsPageModule {}
```

Comment: Please show you ContactsPageModule file.

Comment: I suspect there is some circular dependency going on here. I’ve had this happen to myself quite a bit while refactoring. It might seem extreme, but if you are stuck I would comment out the inner portion of the ts file to basically look like a brand a new component (not actually need any of the imports). And all of the html. 

Then line by line comment out the imports re compiling each time until the error subsided. Just a note, this could be an error from the concatcsmodalModule. So you may have to both.

Comment: Hi - thanks for comment, what do mean by ‘add all of the html’? I did note an warning  during a build about circular dependency but I managed ti resolve it.

Comment: I mean to comment out all of the HTML to eliminate the possibility that some piece of the HTML is the issue. I'm mainly saying that if you comment out everything and slowly add back imports you will be able to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go

Comment: try importing CallNumber from  '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';

Comment: Well tried everything  but could not resolve the issue, so have deleted the modal and all references to it. Before I start trying a modal again is there a good alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try importing CallNumber from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';  in contactmodal.page.ts

```
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
```

Also, add CallNumber as a provider in the  contact.module.ts

```
 import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx';
...    
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    ContactmodalPageModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: ContactsPage}])
  
  ],
  declarations: [ContactsPage],
  providers: [CallNumber]
})
```

Both imported from '@ionic-native/call-number/ngx'

Comment: thanks for that, I spend two days on the problem, how did u know it was the callNumber import ?

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same problem with other plugins when migrating from ionic 3 to 4. If @ionic-native/core version is > 4.20.0, all imports must include /ngx in the path.